# Encrypted home not mounting after upgrade

Tags: mount, lubuntu

I am using lubuntu 14.04 ( 64 bit) with encrypted home directory. I did an upgrade from command line using "sudo do-release-upgrade".

After the upgrade I am unable to login to my home. The splash screen say that home directory is not mounted.

Can someone suggest a solution. If you need more info, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "I did dist upgrade from command line"?